# What syntax error am i getting in writing a simple for loop in the javascript console?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to practice some javascript on the chrome javascript console. 
I read up on the the syntax of javascript's for loop http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp and saw that it was nearly identical to java's. 
Here is the simple for loop i tried running on the console.

```
for(int count = 0; count < 10; count ++ ) { alert("hi"); }
```

And the syntax error I am getting

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Does anyone know why this syntax error is occuring. It can't be because of alert because i tested that and read that that was the function to use to pop up an alert box. [Alert javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp)

And nothing on here https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console suggests that you can't run for loops in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace int with var

```
for(var count = 0; count < 10; count ++ ) { alert("hi"); }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no int-keyword in javascript, to declare a variable use var:

```
for(var count = 0; count < 10; count ++ ) { alert("hi"); }
```

Comment: Yeah I was tripped up a bit because the link i went on didn't include var and i was under the assumption that javascript is pretty much identical to java